# how to display message box on clicking submit button in google form?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

I have written a script in spreadsheet of a corresponding google form. I need to display a Message box displaying the value of "rand" as shown in the script code below in the picture.

Can anyone help me with the code for displaying the required message box. Please go through the script which is written in the script editor of the spreadsheet(corresponding to the google form).

Please go through the code and suggest any solution
[Sciptcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TCrC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't interact with a **google form** from **apps script**. Your apps script is triggered **on form submit** and it does not give any feedback to the google form. If you want to give your user a confirmation message you should consider sending him an email from your triggered script.